# Login to community as system admin on custom button click not working

Tags: apex, community

When we Login into community from Salesforce Internal Org from global header Salesforce we use this URL

> PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/servlet/networks/switch?networkId=NetworkId');

I want to use this functionality on custom button click. When we use this URL in our custom button action method it works fine and takes us to the community landing page the first time it's used as would be expected. But, if we visit some standard page in the Community then come back into our Salesforce Internal org from the community, the next time we attempt to go to the community as a system admin by clicking on the custom button, instead of taking us to the landing Page, it takes us to the last community page we were on before returning to the internal Salesforce Org.

How can I solve this problem so that each time we click on the button we always go to the community landing page?

Comment: Have you tried adding the ID to the URL when you are constructing it?

Comment: Yes i tried but no success

Comment: When you say no success do you mean the ID did not get appended to the url (if so what code did you use) or that something else did not happen. You are going to need to clarify your question as it is quite unclear as to what you are doing to get the url and what it not working.....

Comment: i pass the id with URL but in the community Landing Page i don't get any ID in The URL. Basically i want to Redirect user to community from account detail Page and i want to pass id for further processing in community but i don't find any way to do this.

Comment: I want to login in community as System admin without using the global header.

Comment: I edited the question and clarify my problem and add additional details.

Comment: Is your problem because you aren't putting an actual Id on the end of the PageReference?

Comment: @dphil no i am putting actual ID here. I wrote Network Id here for reference only.